# Remainder of $3^7/8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I read [here](http://www.urch.com/forums/gre-math/133792-please-help-q-3.html#post869216) that the remainder of $\frac{ab}{c}$ is equal to the remainder of $\frac{a}{c}\frac{b}{c}$ implying that the remainder of $\frac{a^b}{c}$ is equal to the remainder of $[\frac{a}{c}]^b$. However, when I apply this here, I would get remainder of $[\frac{3}{8}]^7=3^7$ (while the correct answer is $3$). What am I doing wrong here? And if this method is not valid, are there other *quick and simple* methods of finding remainders like this?

Comment: Your question and the title of your question have different expressions.

Comment: It's easy to disprove your first claim: remainder of $5\times7$ divided by $11$ is $3$, and remainder of $5/11$ and $7/11$ are respectively $5$ and $7$. However, $5\times7\neq3$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut So the post on the link is incorrect?

Comment: @Timbuc I don't think so. I already simplified the expression in the title with the rule that is claimed to hold in in the link.

Comment: @student234234 Yes. Notice that the same numbers will disprove also the second claim in that message.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks! Can you suggest any other quick ways of computing remainders of products or exponents such as these?

Comment: @student234234, it's not the same $\;\frac{3^7}8\;$ and $\;\lfloor\frac38\rfloor^7\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remainder of $ \frac {ab}{c}$ = remainder of $ \frac {a}{c} $ $\times$ remainder of $ \frac {b}{c} $ is FALSE in most cases.

When remainder of $ \frac {a}{c} $ $\times$ remainder of $ \frac {b}{c} \lt c$, only then it is valid.

However when remainder of $ \frac {a}{c} $ $\times$ remainder of $ \frac {b}{c} \ge c$, then

Remainder of $ \frac {ab}{c}$ = Remainder of $ \frac {remainder  of  \frac {a}{c} \times remainder of  \frac {b}{c} }{c}$

Since as you wrote: remainder of $ \frac {a}{c} $ $\times$ remainder of $ \frac {b}{c} = 3^7$ and dividing $ 3^7 $ by $8$ is the very problem we started at,

To apply the rule in this case, you could make use of the fact that:

$$ 3^7 = 3^4 \times 3^ 3$$

So assume $a$ to be $3^4$ and $b$ to be $3^3$.

Now, it's quite easy to calculate that $3^4 = 81 $ and $3^3 = 27 $

Remainder of $ \frac {3^7}{8} $ = Remainder of $ \frac {3^4 \times 3^3}{8}$ = Remainder of $ \frac {81 \times 27}{8} $

By the rule, Remainder of $ \frac {81 \times 27}{8} $ = Remainder of $ \frac {81}{8} $ $ \times $ Remainder of $\frac {27}{8} $ = $1 \times 3 $ = $3$

Since $ 3 \lt 8$, this is indeed our answer.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was also already thinking of this, since all the examples given in the link also show the case in which $a,b>c$. This certainly seems the easiest method to get to the answer! It would be nice if we could prove the claim that the rule is true in this particular case, but it at least seems to hold up.

Comment: @student234234 I have edited the post with a necessary correction. Please see, and while I can't give a proof of this, this should be true.

Comment: Hmmh, sorry but I don't think that the new version of your answer is clearer. You first say that the product of the separate remainders should be $\geq 8$ and you conclude with the fact that $3<8$ so that it holds true. I think that the previous version of your answer was better.

Comment: Also, how do you get to the condition that it should be smaller than 8?

Comment: Ah, sorry since we took the denominator as 8, it stuck in my mind. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic):

$$3^2=9\equiv1\pmod{8}$$
So
$$3^7=(3^2)^3\times 3\equiv 1\times 3\equiv3\pmod{8}$$

Remember that $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ means that $a$ and $b$ have same remainder when divided by $m$. It's also equivalent to $m|a-b$ (you read it *$m$ divides $a-b$*).

And with congruences you can write that if $a\equiv b \pmod{m}$ and $c\equiv d \pmod{m}$, then, among others:

$$ac\equiv bd \pmod{m}$$
$$a+c\equiv b+d \pmod{m}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this is very useful!

Comment: One question that I have: In the second line of equations you seem to use that since you know that $(3^2) \mod 8 = 1$ and $3 \mod 8 = 1$ that their product is also $1$ (which looks the same as the rule that I wrote in the OP). What is different here from that rule?

Comment: @student234234 You need an "extra remainder" for the formula to hold. For example $16\times29=464\equiv2\pmod{11}$. And you have $16\equiv5\pmod{11}$ and $29\equiv7\pmod{11}$, but $5\times7=35\neq 2$. However, with the "extra remainder" $5\times7=35\equiv2\pmod{11}$ and it's ok. (in my comment above, there is a little mistake, I wrote $3$ instead of $2$. Also, notice that $3\not\equiv1\pmod{8}$, it's $3^2\equiv1\pmod{8}$.

Comment: @student234234 Actually, the page you link to is doing congruence arithmetic the wrong way: you need to take remainder at each step so that your numbers are all kept in $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ where $n$ is the "modulus" (there is an added "Remainder of" in Swapnil's answer for example). Or another way to see this, you are computing with [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of numbers (it's the more modern mathematical way to view congruences).

Comment: Thanks you very much. Would upvote if I could (don't have enough reputation), but the other answer is somewhat easier for me. Really appreciate your effort though!